# regexp split string by commas and spaces, but ignore hyphenated words?

Tags: ruby, regex

I need a regexp to split a string by commas and/or spaces, but ignore hyphenated words -- what's the best way to do this?

so, for example -- I'd like this ...

```
"foo bar, zap-foo, baz".split(/[\s]+/)
```

to return

```
["foo", "bar", "zap-foo", "baz"]
```

but when I do that it includes the commas like this ...

```
["foo", "bar,", "zap-foo,", "baz"]
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`"foo bar, zap-foo, baz".split(/[\s,]+/)`

Comment: `["foo", "bar", "zap-foo", "baz"]` is the output but can we **NOT** split `["foo bar"]` as `["foo" and "bar"]`

Answer (score 5):

You can specify a character class which says to split on things that are not hyphens or word characters:

```
"foo bar, zap-foo, baz".split(/[^\w-]+/)
```

Or you can split only on whitespace and commas using a character class such as the one [Ocson has provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835032/regexp-split-string-by-commas-and-spaces-but-ignore-hyphenated-words/1835128#1835128).

Answer (score 3):

Or if you want to be REALLY explicit about the separators:

```
"foo bar, zap-foo, baz".split(/ |, |,/)

=> ["foo", "bar", "zap-foo", "baz"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"foo bar, zap-foo, baz".split(/[\s.,]+/)
```